# jquery not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: jquery, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying writing html pages in ubuntu 14.04. My server is Apache2. I wrote jquery code in the html file. The html contents appears on  browser but jquery is not working. Please help me with what should I do to get jquery working in ubuntu. Below I am giving the simple html file I am working on:

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("p").click(function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>I will disappear. </p>
    <p> Click me away! </p>
    <p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Also, script tags aren't self-closing. The syntax highlighter tips you off to that.

Comment: If this issue *actually* has anything to do with the fact that you're using ubuntu 14.04, I'll eat my left shoe. --- On a more serious/helpful note, put an alert("inside click!") to confirm if the event is being fired when you expect. If it doesn't happen, then something's wrong with how you're including jQuery etc

Comment: @j08691 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is javascript that runs in the browser. The fact that you are on Ubuntu has absolutely nothing to do with the fact that the javascript isn't working.

Inspect your request (net tab in dev tools) to make sure the jQuery library is loaded correctly. Anything showing in red? A 404 response? If you filter by js, is the jQuery library even in there?

Strictly speaking script tags can not be self closing. So your jQuery script should be loaded like this:

```
<script src="./jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

I doubt the browser will actually trip over the self closing tag, but correct is correct. I suspect it is just an issue with the (relative) file path.

Comment: Thank you for the tip off. script tag should not be self closing.